# How to take screenshots in a module in geb

Tags: spock, geb

Hi we run Geb tests on the Spock framework. I am trying to take a screenshot in a module using report "Screenshot". It does not recognize the report function as it does on a Spec. How should I go about taking screenshots in a module.

Here is a example code which is in a module.

```
try{
    $(By.xpath("//button[@ng-click=\"ok()\"]")).click()
   }
catch (Throwable t){
                                                                  failures.add("\n Could not click on the Ok button after the Ticket created successfully message appeared")

report "Failure"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `report()` method is available on `Browser` class and an instance of that class is available as `browser` property inside of modules, so you can call it from within a module using:

```
browser.report("Failure")
```

Comment: @VinuMahalingam can you please mark this answer as the right one?

Answer (score 0):

Use the parent class `GebReportingSpec` (instead of `GebSpec`) to create a report of all your tests.

When you only want a screenshot of failing tests, use the config value `reportOnTestFailureOnly=true` in your GebConfig.groovy